# Knockout with require.js - not looking for knockout in my configured 'paths' section

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs, amd

I’m developing a multi-page app, using requirejs to manage my javascript libs / dependencies.
My idea is that i'll have a main.js that holds the config, and then an .js file for each page that needs it, for example "register.js"

My require config is in `javascripts/main.js`

```
requirejs.config({
     baseUrl: '/javascripts',
     waitSeconds: 200,
     paths: {
          'async': 'lib/require.async',
          'jquery': 'lib/jquery-1.7.2.min',
          'knockout': 'lib/knockout-3.0.0'
});
```

I’ve got a knockout view model that looks like this:
javascripts/viewModels/userDetailsViewModel.js

```
define(['knockout'], function(ko) {
    return function() {
        var self = this;

        self.name = ko.observable();
        self.email = ko.observable();
});
```

My ‘entry point’ is javascripts/register.js

```
require(['./main', 'knockout', 'viewModels/userDetailsViewModel'], function(main, ko, userDetailsViewModel) {
    ko.applyBindings(new userDetailsViewModel());
});
```

On my register.html page, i’ve got the script reference like this:

```
<script data-main="/javascripts/register" src="/javascripts/lib/require.js"></script>
```

When my page loads, I get these errors in the console:

> GET `http://localhost:3000/javascripts/knockout.js` 404 (Not Found)

and

> Uncaught Error: Script error for: knockout

I’m not sure why it’s looking for `knockout.js` - I’ve specified knockout in the paths section of my config, to look in lib/knockout-3.0.0

My dir structure is:

**javascripts/**
Most of my pages js files go here

**javascripts/viewModels**
Has knockout viewmodels

**javascripts/lib**
Contains knockout, jquery, requirejs etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that RequireJS will execute the call `require(['./main', 'knockout', 'viewModels/userDetailsViewModel']` without a configuration. Yes, `./main` is listed before `knockout` but there is no order guarantee between the dependencies passed in a *single* `require` call. RequireJS may load `./main` first, or `knockout` first. And even if `./main` were loaded first by this specific call, I believe it would not have any impact on how the other modules loaded by *this* call would load. That is, I think this `require` would operate on the basis of the configuration that existed at the time it was *called*, and that any configuration changes caused by the modules it loads would take effect only for *subsequent* `require` calls.

There are many ways to fix this. This should work:

```
require(['./main', function(main) {
    require(['knockout', 'viewModels/userDetailsViewModel'], function(ko,  userDetailsViewModel) {
        ko.applyBindings(new userDetailsViewModel());
    });
});
```

Or you might want to restructure your files and what you pass to `data-main` so that your `requirejs.config` is loaded *and* executed before your first `require` call. Here's an example of restructuring. Change your entry point to be `/javascripts/main.js`:

```
<script data-main="/javascripts/main.js" src="/javascripts/lib/require.js"></script>
```

Change `/javascripts/main.js` so that it contains:

```
requirejs.config({
     baseUrl: '/javascripts',
     waitSeconds: 200,
     paths: {
          'async': 'lib/require.async',
          'jquery': 'lib/jquery-1.7.2.min',
          'knockout': 'lib/knockout-3.0.0'
});

require(['knockout', 'viewModels/userDetailsViewModel'], function(ko, userDetailsViewModel) {
    ko.applyBindings(new userDetailsViewModel());
});
```

And remove `/javascripts/register.js`. This would be one way to do it. However, it is hard for me to tell whether this would be what you want in your *specific* project, because I do not know the *whole* project. The way to restructure for your specific project really depends on what other pages might use RequireJS, what information is common to all pages, what is specific to each page, whether you use a template system to produce HTML, etc.

Comment: That makes sense... Thank you. Could you elaborate on your restructure files point please, i'm curious!

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: I see, thanks. First method works best for me in this project. Thank you